# Messages filtration gateway that works against a messages database?

Tags: filter

My question might seem a bit vague: Is there any email filtration gateway that works by checking a messages database? I know that is already considered under anti-spam methods, but I would like to know if there is a gateway which I can install on Windows/Linux, and then I, as an administrator, start adding messages under it that I consider "bad", and then it can help me catch any emails that are sent to/through this server/gateway. For example, say I would like to store 10 emails that I consider false, and then whenever an email is sent through my mailing gateway, goes through this filtration process, checks those 10 emails against that email, and then take action based on it (eg. maybe reply back saying this email matches/nearly matches one in the database).

I don't want to use this anti-spam like gateway for emails such as advertising, and so.. I just want to use it to check against a specific database of emails, and kind of return the % of match with the database (which will be expanded by time).

Comment: Well, I guess I used the wrong term. It is not an anti "spam" that I want. Sorry. You can count it as a filtration technology where I can specify what emails to match to consider "bad". It has nothing to do with SPAM, as I want to use it for other internal uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the Lamson project. http://lamsonproject.org.

It's a framework for writing applications that handle mail.  You can implement very sophisticated mail handling.